# Creating a rolling/moving window in a 3d numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I currently use the following code to create a 4d array which consists out of moving windows for each raster layer in a 3d array (dimensions are: time, x, y).

```
import numpy as np
import progressbar
import copy

def moving_window_array(array, window_size, overlap):
    sz = array.itemsize
    shape = array.shape
    array = np.ascontiguousarray(array)

    strides = (sz * shape[1] * (window_size - overlap),
               sz * (window_size - overlap), sz * shape[1], sz)
    shape = (int((shape[0] - window_size) / (window_size - overlap)) + 1, int(
        (shape[1] - window_size) / (window_size - overlap)) + 1, window_size, window_size)

    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(array, strides=strides, shape=shape).reshape(-1, window_size, window_size)


def rolling_3d_window(arr, ws, ol, dim=0):
    bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=arr.shape[dim], widgets=[progressbar.Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', progressbar.Percentage()]) 
    bar.start()
    bar_iterator = 0
    mvwd_out = []
    for i in range(0, arr.shape[dim]):
        mvwd = moving_window_array(arr[i], window_size=ws, overlap=ol)
        mvwd = np.reshape(mvwd,(1,mvwd.shape[0],mvwd.shape[1], mvwd.shape[2]))
        mvwd_out.append(mvwd)
        bar.update(bar_iterator+1)
        bar_iterator += 1
    return(mvwd_out)
#Testing:
test_arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(30, 10, 10))
test_out = rolling_3d_window(test_arr, 3, 2)
test_out = np.array(test_out)
```

As known, the for loop is the most costly part in the code.
Now I am wondering if there is any possibility to make the strides work to give me the moving window without the for loop.
Thanks in advance for any help.

EDIT: @hpaulj made me aware that np.append is not optimal to use in a for loop. I adjusted the code accordingly to a list. This speeds up the code significantly but uses more memory. The question in total however remains.

Comment: The [sliding window view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html#numpy-lib-stride-tricks-sliding-window-view) is slightly more user-friendly for this application I think

Comment: It's hard to tell what you are doing different in each loop.  Looks like the same `moving_window_array` each time?  And by now you should have learned that repeated `np.append` in a loop is a bad idea.  If you must loop, collect values in a list, making the array once at the end.  While `as_stirded` makes a view, `reshape` after usually forces a copy.

Comment: The np.append however resolves the issue of RAM overflow. When running the code with a list it's much faster correct, however I need to allocate twice as much RAM when trying to transfer the list into an array. 

The loop is there to create a moving window in each layer of the time dimension.